# Reverse highmaps legend values or color OR draw legend color from other attribute instead of value in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse, legend, highmaps

here is my highmaps
http://jsfiddle.net/waqarakbar/8fypgxvc/

 I need to reverse the values of the legend so that 30 go to top (red color) and 0 
come to bottom (green color). Reversing either the values or the color gradient will solve my problem. I have tried

```
colorAxis: {
    reversed:false
}
```

but it reverse both, values and color (I need only one to be reversed). I have also tried

```
legend: {
    reversed: true
}
```

but it seems to be not working at all...


**Another possible solution** that will solve my problem is to draw the legend based on some other attribute instead of "value" attribute. Highmaps is using the value of "value" attribute to draw the color gradient of the legend, in my case, i would like to draw it on the basis of "rank" attribute that i assigned to districts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace colors

```
   minColor: '#26c40d',
    maxColor: '#e51414',
```

> Update 1

try with the option

```
         colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 26,
        step:2,
        minColor: '#e51414',
        maxColor: '#26c40d',
        align: 'top',
        reversed : false
    },
```

[image]

Here are some more options 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.reversed

Comment: I have to use green color for highest number and red for lowest. its client's requirement.

Comment: Now the the legend is showing correct information (red for lowest and green for highest) but the map is reversed, i.e red for highest and green for lowest.
I have read almost all api documentation of highmaps but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: using reverse in colorAxis just flip the whole legend, still 30 is green and 0 is red. I need 30 to be red and 0 to be green.

Comment: I have updated the question and added another possibility to solve this issue, let me know if you can help me with that possibility....